# Resetting values to original on click of reset button for date in Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on a page which requires the date to be reset to original value on click of reset button but once you enter a value in the date field and try resetting it retains the date value and doesn't reset back to placeholder value.Here is the code

```
 <div class="filterPanel">
    <span class="filterPanelHeader">Payment Date</span>
        <input type="date" data-datepicker="{theme: 'flat'}"
         data-role="date" id="paymentDateFrom"
         name="paymentDateFrom" ng-model="paymentFromDate"
         placeholder="From Date" />                             
 </div>
```

I am using a reset button

```
<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-6">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="reset()">
     <span class="icon-ico_redo_rnd_lg  icon-ico_redo_rnd_sm"></span>Reset                                      
  </button>
</div>
```

Below is the javascript i am using for reset().

```
$scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.setFilterData();
        $scope.resetDates();
        $scope.submitFilter();
        console.log($scope.filterData);
        console.log($scope.invoiceFromDate);
    }

$scope.resetDates=function() {
        console.log($scope.invoiceFromDate);
        $scope.filterForm.$setPristine();
        $scope.filterForm.$setUntouched();
        console.log($scope.invoiceFromDate);
        $scope.invoiceFromDate=null;        
    }
```

I want to set the value of the paymentDateFrom to it's placeholder value how to do that?

Comment: `$scope.invoiceFromDate=null;` or `$scope.paymentDateFrom=null;   `

Comment: or `delete $scope.invoiceFromDate`

Comment: @Rakeschand tried both in the function both of them doesn't reset it to placeholder value.